# PHP loops to check that a set of numbers are consecutive

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop through a set of records, all of which have a "number" property. I am trying to check if there are 3 consecutive records, e.g 6, 7 and 8.

I think i'm almost there with the code below, have hit the wall though at the last stage - any help would be great!

```
$nums = array();
while (count($nums <= 3))
{
    //run through entries (already in descending order by 'number'
    foreach ($entries as $e)
    {
        //ignore if the number is already in the array, as duplicate numbers may exist
        if (in_array($e->number, $num))
            continue;
        else
        {
            //store this number in the array
            $num[] = $e->number;
        }
    //here i need to somehow check that the numbers stored are consecutive
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function isConsecutive($array) {
    return ((int)max($array)-(int)min($array) == (count($array)-1));
}
```

You can achieve the same result without looping, too.

Comment: `isConsecutive([1,3,0,0])` returns what now?

Comment: As mentioned above. This doesn't do what you might expect.

Answer (score 1):

If they just have to be consecutive, store a $last, and check to make sure $current == $last + 1.

If you're looking for n numbers that are consecutive, use the same, except also keep a counter of how many ones fulfilled that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,343,6543,234,23432,100,101,102,103,200,201,202,203,204);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr);$i++)
{ 
    if(isset($arr[$i+1]))
    if($arr[$i]+1==$arr[$i+1])
    {

        if(isset($arr[$i+2]))
        if($arr[$i]+2==$arr[$i+2]) 
        {

            if(isset($arr[$i+3]))       
            if($arr[$i]+3==$arr[$i+3])
            { 
                echo 'I found it:',$arr[$i],'|',$arr[$i+1],'|',$arr[$i+2],'|',$arr[$i+3],'<br>'; 
            }//if3

        }//if 2

    }//if 1
}
```

I haven't investigated it thoroughly, maybe can be improved to work faster!

Answer (score 1):

This will confirm if all items of an array are consecutive either up or down.
You could update to return an array of [$up, $down] or another value instead if you need direction.

```php
function areAllConsecutive($sequence)
{
    $up = true;
    $down = true;
    foreach($sequence as $key => $item)
    {
        if($key > 0){
            if(($item-1) != $prev) $up = false;
            if(($item+1) != $prev) $down = false;
        }
        $prev = $item;
    }

    return $up || $down;
}

// areAllConsecutive([3,4,5,6]); // true
// areAllConsecutive([3,5,6,7]); // false
// areAllConsecutive([12,11,10,9]); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that can check this requirement for a list of any size:

```
class MockNumber
{
    public $number;
    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    static public function IsListConsecutive(array $list)
    {
        $result = true;
        foreach($list as $n)
        {
            if (isset($n_minus_one) && $n->number !== $n_minus_one->number + 1)
            {
                $result = false;
                break;
            }

            $n_minus_one = $n;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

$list_consecutive = array(
     new MockNumber(0)
    ,new MockNumber(1)
    ,new MockNumber(2)
    ,new MockNumber(3)
);

$list_not_consecutive = array(
     new MockNumber(5)
    ,new MockNumber(1)
    ,new MockNumber(3)
    ,new MockNumber(2)
);

printf("list_consecutive %s consecutive\n", MockNumber::IsListConsecutive($list_consecutive) ? 'is' : 'is not');
// output: list_consecutive is consecutive

printf("list_not_consecutive %s consecutive\n", MockNumber::IsListConsecutive($list_not_consecutive) ? 'is' : 'is not');
// output: list_not_consecutive is not consecutive
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like the following function (no need of arrays to store data)

```
<?php
function seqOfthree($entries) {
// entries has to be sorted descending on $e->number
  $sequence = 0;
  $lastNumber = 0;

  foreach($entries as $e) {
    if ($sequence==0 or ($e->number==$lastNumber-1)) {
      $sequence--;
    } else {
      $sequence=1;
    }
    $lastNumber = $e->number;
    if ($sequence ==3) {
      // if you need the array of sequence you can obtain it easy
      // return $records = range($lastNumber,$lastNumber+2);
      return true;
    }
  }
  // there isn't a sequence
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Eineki, the entries are in descending order, how would you modify your code to suit that?

Comment: @pauld78 just revert the + signs into - ones (I've already modified the function to do that)

Answer (score 0):

If u don't wanna mess with any sorting, picking any of three numbers that are consecutive should give you:
- it either is adjacent to both the other numbers (diff1 = 1, diff2 = -1)
- the only number that is adjacent (diff = +-1) should comply the previous statement.

Test for the first condition. If it fails, test for the second one and under success, you've got your secuence; else the set doesn't comply.

Seems right to me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isConsecutive($array, $total_consecutive = 3, $consecutive_count = 1, $offset = 0) {
    // if you run out of space, e.g. not enough array values left to full fill the required # of consecutive count
    if ( $offset + ($total_consecutive - $consecutive_count ) > count($array) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( $array[$offset] + 1 == $array[$offset + 1]) {
        $consecutive_count+=1;
        if ( $consecutive_count == $total_consecutive ) {
            return true;
        }
        return isConsecutive($array, $total_consecutive, $consecutive_count, $offset+=1 );
    } else {
        return isConsecutive($array, $total_consecutive, 1, $offset+=1 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following function will return the index of the first of the consecutive elements, and false if none exist:

```
function findConsecutive(array $numbers)
{
    for ($i = 0, $max = count($numbers) - 2; $i < $max; ++$i)
        if ($numbers[$i] == $numbers[$i + 1] - 1 && $numbers[$i] == $numbers[$i + 2] - 2)
            return $i;
    return false;
}
```

**Edit:** This seemed to cause some confusion. Like [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos), this function returns the *position* of the elements if any such exists. The position may be 0, which can evaluate to false. If you just need to see if they exist, then you can replace `return $i;` with `return true;`. You can also easily make it return the actual elements if you need to.

**Edit 2:** Fixed to *actually* find consecutive numbers.

Comment: I believe this fails for `findConsecutive(array(1,5,9123));`.

Comment: @Frank Farmer how does it fail? It returns int(0), which is the index of the first element of the consecutive three. Note that 0 !== false.

Comment: 1 5 and 9123 are not consecutive.